# Why is Cobertura recompiling my code?

Tags: maven, cobertura

When I run `mvn package`, Cobertura causes all of the compilations steps to run again. I understand that Cobertura will cause the tests to run twice and that's fine. I just don't understand why it would need to recompile my code. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Because it also instruments the code

Comment: This post might help in your understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430254/how-does-cobertura-work-with-junit